# Pass PhoneNumber field as an array

Tags: php, laravel

I am using an online laravel api documentation in my app. When i run my code in my browser, i get the error "pass phonenumber field as an array". But the number field is being already passed as an array field. What could i be missing below in my code ? Thanks in advance

```
public function testAPI(Request $request)
    {
        $on_call_back = 'https://learntoday.co.uk/var';
        $id = '*****';
        $url = $on_call_back.'?key='.$id;
        $variables = [
           'phoneNumber' => ['44234200234','44234242002'],
           'from' => 'world',
           'content' => 'I love to code',
        ];

        $ch = curl_init();
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($variables));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $result = json_decode($result, TRUE);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

When i return $variables, i get the response

```
Array
(
    [phoneNumber] => Array
        (
            [0] => 44234200234
            [1] => 44234242002
        )

    [from] => test
    [content] => I love to code

)
{"status":"error","message":"Make sure you are passing the phoneNumber field as an array"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($variables));
```

to

<strike>curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $variables);</strike>

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($variables));
```

You can also do `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` instead of `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`.

Comment: After changing that line of code, i get the error `Array to string conversion`

Comment: @CodeNewbie Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax of the array seems to be wrong, have you tried putting each number into single quotes like this:

```
 'phoneNumber' => ['44234200234', '44234242002'],
```

Comment: @CodeNewbie again on your edit, you are missing a closing single quote on your first number

Comment: Okay.. Thanks.. I just updated and re-run the code, but same error please

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$variables = [
           'phoneNumber' => ['44234200234','44234242002'],
           'from' => 'world',
           'content' => 'I love to code',
        ];
```

**Updated answer**

```
public function testAPI(Request $request)
    {
        $on_call_back = 'https://learntoday.co.uk/var';
        $id = '*****';
        $url = $on_call_back.'?key='.$id;
        $variables = [
           'phoneNumber' => ['44234200234','44234242002'],
           'from' => 'world',
           'content' => 'I love to code',
        ];

        $ch = curl_init();
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($variables));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $result = json_decode($result, TRUE);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try send $variable as below code

```
$variables = array(
           'phoneNumber' => array('44234200234','44234242002'),
           'from' => 'world',
           'content' => 'I love to code',
        );
```